# Android 5.0 select tag empty in webview

Tags: android, select, webview

I m trying to show a simple select tag in a webview

```
<select >
   <option value = "1" selected>Value 1</option>
   <option value="2">Value 2</option>
    <option value="3">Value 3</option>
</select>
```

MainActivity.java :

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView); 

    ProgressBar progressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressbar);

    //WebSettings webSettings = webView.getSettings();
    //webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

    // A activer pour surcharger la méthode onJsAlert
    //webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());

    //webView.setWebViewClient(new MegViewClient(this, progressBar));

    // Récupération d'un instance sauvegardée
    if (savedInstanceState != null)
        webView.restoreState(savedInstanceState);
    else {
        webView.loadUrl("http://myUrl");
    }   

  if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
      WebView.setWebContentsDebuggingEnabled(true);
  }
}
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
 <uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="21" />
```

I tried with both webViewClient and with webchromeClient but I got the same result :

**the select is visible but the list of option is empty.**

if I try on a tablet with android 4.4, the select is wellformed.

Comment: +1 and why the down vote? I'm running into this as well. I did find the Google bug referenced below, but StackOverflow is a great place to find stuff like this and to find peoples workarounds.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's seems to be a chromium bug : [Issue 80909: HTML SELECT options dropdown appears blank in lollipop webview](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=80909)

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem. My workaround is to use this jquery tool ([select2](https://github.com/select2/select2)) to replace all selects.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/3.5.2/select2.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdn.jsdelivr.net/select2/3.5.2/select2.min.js"></script>

<select >
   <option value = "1" selected>Value 1</option>
   <option value="2">Value 2</option>
    <option value="3">Value 3</option>
</select>

<script>
// replace all select inputs with select2
$("select").select2();

// remove the search tool inside select2
$(".select2-search, .select2-focusser").remove(); 
</script>
```

Comment: I am using this now as well. Really too bad they won't fix it. FYI - you don't need to remove the search tool. Just generate without it: $("select").select2({ minimumResultsForSearch: Infinity });